# Visual Studio Code doesn't work with Xdebug

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-22.04, xdebug-3

Firstly, I want to inform you that English is not my first language, and I apologize for my imperfect English.

I configured Xdebug to debug in VSCode. Three icons of Xdebug are inactive (Step into Step out, Step Over).

The Xdebug configuration seems good:

`php -v` gives:

```
gerard@gerard-ThinkCentre-M700:~$ php -v
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2023 11:41:11) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

My Xdebug configuration (`/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini`) **:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = develop, debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9003
```

[image: xdebug1]
[image: Xdebug2]
[image: Xdebug3]

And this is the `xdebug.log` (the message is also present in Xdebug_info.php):

```
[10694] Log opened at 2024-03-15 08:52:39.285551
[10694] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[10694] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[10694] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_p>
[10694] Log closed at 2024-03-15 08:52:39.287093

[10696] Log opened at 2024-03-15 08:52:39.308197
[10696] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[10696] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[10696] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_p>
[10696] Log closed at 2024-03-15 08:52:39.308848

[10852] Log opened at 2024-03-15 08:52:58.522332
[10852] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[10852] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[10852] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_p>
[10852] Log closed at 2024-03-15 08:52:58.524340

[10853] Log opened at 2024-03-15 08:52:58.549547
[10853] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[10853] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[10853] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_p>
[10853] Log closed at 2024-03-15 08:52:58.550293
```

" netstat -an | grep 9003" give when debugger is active:

```
gerard@gerard-ThinkCentre-M700:~$ netstat -an | grep 9003
tcp6       0      0 :::9003                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

`launch.json` of VSCode:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

** https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/installing-xdebug-3-on-php-8-1-ubuntu-20-4-and-using-it-with-magento-2-4/

Comment: Which of the two launch configurations are you using? One way is the "listen" style, where VS sits and waits for an XDebug connection. This can be established by e.g. a web request in the browser or via commandline. The second style "launch" is that a script is started with the debugger connected.

Comment: BTW: I wouldn't use PEAR/PECL as the tutorial suggests. Instead, install the backports from https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php instead. The maintainer of those is also the official maintainer for Debian and Ubuntu, so I'd call those trustworthy.

Comment: I use one configurations (CLI and WEB). I've created tow links. So there is only one file for the web and CLI configurations:
https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/installing-xdebug-3-on-php-8-1-ubuntu-20-4-and-using-it-with-magento-2-4/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You have two "configurations" in the "launch.json" file. Which one are you using? And how precisely? Please describe that as clearly as possible in your question.

Comment: I use the cli configuration. When i want to debug whith VScode appears. Three of six icons are disabled (with or without breakpoints): Steo Over, Steo int, Step out.
The launch.json is up

Comment: Try a simple script and put a call to `xdebug_break()` in there. It should stop at this point and then, those three icons in the debugger toolbar should activate. Until it hits a breakpoint, only those three titled pause, restart and stop are active.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it, but the problem is still present.

Comment: Have you checked possible firewall settings?

Comment: The debugger was working before.
when debugger is activated, netstat -an | grep 9003 give
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
code    22724 gerard   26u  IPv6 200996      0t0  TCP *:9003 (LISTEN)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Xdebug with VSCode works in two ways:

1 - with a CLI session (without server and with no launch.json: configuration file):

- Open your file on VSCode.
- Set breakpoint(s)
- Start your application with the "Start Debugging" option. The debugger becomes operational.

2 - with a local server web with a launch.json:

- Open your file with VSCode
- Create the launch.json file (in the section Run and debug on the left). Save it.
- Set breakpoint(s)
- Start your application with the "Start Debugging" option.
- Run your file with web browser (localhost/my-progam.php). The debugger is launched on VSCode.

3 -With the PHP web server:

- Launch the server with PHP using:

```php
php -S localhost:8082
```

The port number 8082 can be changed.

- Create a launch.json file if necessary (in the "Run and Debug" section on the left).
- Run with the option "Start Debugging".
- Launch an HTTP request with Postman, for example.
- Debugging should start.

You can read what I said here: https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/visual_studio_code#serveurs_web_internes (partie 2.3)